# Checking if a point is in a circle

Tags: python, geodjango, geos, shapely

I'm using shapely to check if a point is in a polygon, but I also need to check if a point is in a circle. Checking the docs, I don't see how do that...

Maybe I could create a circle?

`circle = (x,y).buffer(R)`

But it doesn't seem to work using R in miles distance to set the ratio...

Is it possible? Or is there another lib to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christian, you can't have your circle center and point in long,lat space and have R with mile units. Computational geometry algorithms require you to choose one coordinate system. Latitude and longitude is not a good one to work in, by the way unless your objects are very small in extent. After you transform your points to a local coordinate system and scale R to the units of that systems (meters, say), your test with shapely is like this:

```
Point(cx, cy).distance(Point(px, py)) <= R
```

where cx, cy is the center of your circle and px, py is your point. In units of the local coordinate system, not long/lat.

Comment: wow, you are right Sean... I'm working over it, Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [distance_lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lte) function in geodjango to check if your point is in a circle or not. It is the same as ST_Distance method in PostGIS.

The method which I have mentioned is drawing a 5 meter radius of a circle to find points from Zipcode models.

> Returns models where the distance to the geometry field from the
>   lookup geometry is less than or equal to the given distance value.

Example:

```
Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__distance_lte=(geom, D(m=5)))
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks Aragon, but not in all cases I have a zip code for the location, instead I need use a (latitude,longitude) format to set the point.

Comment: @Christian_Espinoza, this is an example code for you to seeing it how the function is using. you can create your own model from lon,lat to check them all.